# Change "Reviews" text in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I need to change the Woo Product Tabs text in my Woocommerce products from "Reviews" to "Testimonials" please help with the correct code.

I tried finding the correct code snippet but could not find the correct solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to following code snippet that goes in `functions.php`.

```
function change_reviews_tab_text( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['reviews']['title'] = 'Testimonials';
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'change_reviews_tab_text' );
```